# Is this SQL statement vulnerable to SQL injection?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

My index action is

```
def index
  @users = User.without_user(current_user)
end
```

where `without_user` is a scope

```
scope :without_user, lambda {|user| where("id <> :id", :id => user.id) }
```

I was wondering if this is the most secure way to implement this or is it vulnerable ?

Comment: If your user's id is not an sql injection than you are OK)

Comment: Looks good to me. As long as you're not interpolating user input you should be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks fine. If the data is interpolated then it should be safe which looks like the case here.

Answer (score 2):

It looks good, here sql injection will not work

Note Additional, In Rails 4, you can use not syntax:

```
scope :without_user, lambda {|user| where.not(id: user.id) }
```

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, what's wrong with syntax sugar of lambda ?

Comment: @SharvyAhmed I'm not sure if you saw my reject reason, but `-> {` doesn't work in all Ruby versions. And some Ruby versions break when using a space between `->` and `{`. Since the original question uses `lambda` (and not `->`), it would make more sense to keep the same style in the answer.